# Percentile for COMPLEX SURVEY DATA while using subpop option

Tags: stata

I am using a survey sample and am trying to analyze a subpopulation.

I am trying to get mean, median, 10th percentile and 90th percentile of a continuous varaible for my subpopulation of interets.

Stata website http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/statistics/percentiles-for-survey-data/ shows the metod to obtain median/percentiles.

However, I am interested in sub population  and not the entire sample. 
Can you please show me the appropriate commands to obtain any percentile while using a complex survey sample with sub population option?

Comment: You cross posted at two other locations, but neglected to give them. Please do in case other answers arise.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `_pctile` to get percentiles for a subpopulation without `svyset`, because the percentiles depend only on the weights.  However to get standard errors and confidence intervals, you should download `epctile` by Stas Kolenikov (`findit epctile` in Stata)  *and* `svyset` the data.

```
net describe epctile, from(http://web.missouri.edu/~kolenikovs/stata)
net install epctile.pkg
```

The auto data will provide the example, with the variable `weight` being the probability weight.

```
sysuse auto, clear
_pctile price if foreign==0 [pw = weight], p(25 50 75)
return list

scalars:
             r(r1) =  4195
             r(r2) =  5104
             r(r3) =  6486
```

Compare to svysetting the data and calling `epctile`:

```
gen strat = rep78
gen mkr = substr(make,1,2)
svyset mkr [pw = weight], strata(strat)
epctile price, percentiles(25 50 75) subpop(if foreign==0) svy
```

Results:

```
Percentile estimation
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         |             Linearized
   price |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]

     p25 |       4195      108.5    38.66   0.000     3982.344    4407.656
     p50 |       5104      320.5    15.93   0.000     4475.832    5732.168
     p75 |       6486       2093     3.10   0.002     2383.795     10588.2
```

Comment: Thank you very much.Sincerely, Anwar